# Loading fasttext binary model from s3 fails

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, gensim, fasttext

I am hosting a pretrained fasttext model on s3 (uncompressed) and I am trying to load it in a lambda function. I am using the `gensim.models.fasttext` module to load the model:

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import load_facebook_vectors

def load_model(obj):
    model = load_facebook_vectors(obj["path"])
```

with `obj["path"]` being the s3 path, but I keep getting the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "fileno"
"errorType": "UnsupportedOperation"
"stackTrace": [
...
"  File \"/var/task/gensim/models/fasttext.py\", line 784, in load_facebook_vectors\n    full_model = _load_fasttext_format(path, encoding=encoding, full_model=False)\n"
"  File \"/var/task/gensim/models/fasttext.py\", line 808, in _load_fasttext_format\n    m = gensim.models._fasttext_bin.load(fin, encoding=encoding, full_model=full_model)\n"
"  File \"/var/task/gensim/models/_fasttext_bin.py\", line 348, in load\n    vectors_ngrams = _load_matrix(fin, new_format=new_format)\n"
"  File \"/var/task/gensim/models/_fasttext_bin.py\", line 282, in _load_matrix\n    matrix = np.fromfile(fin, _FLOAT_DTYPE, count)\n"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `np.fromfile()` method on which this load depends doesn't work on a streamed-from-S3 file.

Some alternate options include:

- download the S3 file to a local path first, then use `load_facebook_vectors()` from there; or…
- while having the FastText file local, load it locally, then use Python's `pickle` functionality to save it to a single file (now of Python's format), then put that file on S3, and in the future re-load it using Python's unpickling

The utility functions in `gensim.utils` `pickle()` and `unpickle()` (which take a file path, including S3 URLs) may be helpful for the 2nd option, eg:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/utils.html#gensim.utils.unpickle

Since your prior code only shows using the vectors (via `.load_facebook_vector`), not the whole model, you could just pickle & upload the `model.wv` subcomponent of the loaded model, rather than the whole model, to save some storage/bandwidth.

If perhaps in future Gensim versions, the `FastText`-model related classes change in shape/operation, an old pickled-model might not cleanly load. In such an eventuality, you could potentially either:

- go back to the original Facebook-format model file (which could then be loaded, & then re-saved in a modern format, again); OR...
- load your pickled model into the older Gensim where it works, save it locally using Gensim's native `.save()` (which may split it over multiple local files), then in the newer Gensim use Gensim's native `FastText.load()` to load those older files (which will usually handle older formats), then re-pickle that loaded model, for future re-unpickles into the matching latest Gensim.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid downloading the S3 file locally (rather have that as last resort), but the pickle idea is quite good. I turned the vectors into a pickle, and using the Gensim pickle functions on my local computer the loading time improved drastically (`load_facebook_vectors` at `~61 seconds`, `pickle` at `~8 seconds`). However, on lambda I no longer get the fileno error, but it times out constantly, even when put at 10240 MB memory.

Comment: Unsure what could be amiss in that situation, & would need to see your code that works local, but times out remote to fully brainstorm what might be happening. In particular: does it time-out always or sometimes? Does a trivially-tiny pickle ever time-out, and is there some specific model-size-threshold that reliably either does or doesn't time-out? (For that matter, can we confirm which Python version is in use, & thus which pickle version is the default?)

Comment: So I tried with a trivially-tiny pickle and found that after the reading the s3 response object's body, the response was a byte string, so I could only use the native pickle.loads() to have it loaded. Also the Python version is 3.8. 
In general I'm not sure if using the Lambda is even the best way of going about it; the fasttext model I need to load is >5GB, so I don't think it will ever finish in a timely fashion.

Comment: After a lot more trial and error I think the actual issue has to do with Python 3.8, and I made a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70905872/overflowerror-when-reading-from-s3-signed-integer-is-greater-than-maximum
But in general this put me in the right direction, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [load_facebook_vectors](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors) says:

> This function uses the smart_open library to open the path. The path may be on a remote host (e.g. HTTP, S3, etc).

There are examples of accessing S3 objects at [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open). I have not personally tried this but I wanted to make sure you eliminated all options before deciding to forcibly download the object and access it locally.