# Overflowerror when reading from s3 - signed integer is greater than maximum

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Reading a large file from S3 ( >5GB) into lambda with the following code:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    response = s3.get_object(
        Bucket="my-bucket",
        Key="my-key"
    )
    
    text_bytes = response['Body'].read()

    ...
    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

However I get the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "signed integer is greater than maximum"
"errorType": "OverflowError"
"stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 13, in lambda_handler\n    text_bytes = response['Body'].read()\n"
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/response.py\", line 77, in read\n    chunk = self._raw_stream.read(amt)\n"
    "  File \"/var/runtime/urllib3/response.py\", line 515, in read\n    data = self._fp.read() if not fp_closed else b\"\"\n"
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 472, in read\n    s = self._safe_read(self.length)\n"
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/http/client.py\", line 613, in _safe_read\n    data = self.fp.read(amt)\n"
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/socket.py\", line 669, in readinto\n    return self._sock.recv_into(b)\n"
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ssl.py\", line 1241, in recv_into\n    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)\n"
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/ssl.py\", line 1099, in read\n    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)\n"
  ]
```

I am using Python 3.8, and I found here an issue with Python 3.8/9 that might be why: https://bugs.python.org/issue42853

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Just a reminder, there are some limitations with Lambda (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html)

Comment: How is this relevant? If I'm reading from S3 and trying to load the file into Lambda's memory (which is sufficiently large enough to hold the data), I don't see how these limits are being reached.

Comment: Then, it's fine. You just said > 5GB. If it would be near 10GB, it could be too big

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the bug you linked to, the core issue in Python 3.8 is the bug with reading more than 1gb at a time.  You can use a variant of the workaround suggested in the bug to read the file in chunks.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = s3.get_object(
        Bucket="-example-bucket-",
        Key="path/to/key.dat"
    )
    buf = bytearray(response['ContentLength'])
    view = memoryview(buf)
    pos = 0
    while True:
        chunk = response['Body'].read(67108864)
        if len(chunk) == 0:
            break
        view[pos:pos+len(chunk)] = chunk
        pos += len(chunk)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

At best, however, you're going to spend a minute or more of each Lambda run just reading from S3.  It would be much better if you could store the file in EFS and read it from there in the Lambda, or use another solution like ECS to avoid reading from a remote data source.

Comment: Why are you reading 67108864 bytes? I mean, what is the source of that number?

Comment: @eduardosufan  It's an arbitrary number, 64MiB here just because it was reasonably efficient in my testing without exhausting local RAM.

Comment: How the new position to read the next chunk is working? I don't understand what view does. I'm running a test and the next read() statement is reading right after the last chunk executed.

Comment: Most implementations of read, and StreamingBody here is no different, pick up from the last position when called multiple times in a row.  This example uses a memoryview to store the final results to avoid building up a byte array as the data is read, which would result in double the memory used in the worst case.

Comment: Adding my 2 cents. In order to get the full data in string format, first you need to convert memoryview to bytes:
data_str = view.tobytes().decode("utf-8")